# Using the glossaries package for English acronyms in German documents

Tags: glossaries

This is a repost of the original message I posted to [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/8042e3769965e45) in August, which is still unanswered there. I'm sorry for reposting, but I want to spread this to a wider readership.

I found couple of similar questions (along with helpful answers) on StackExchange, however, they are more focused on how to deal with the variety of cases the German language has. This is not my actual problem, since the suggested workarounds for this issue are sufficient. They mostly incorporate the use of `\glslink` and `\glsdisp`.

Below is the text of my original post.

I would like to use the glossaries package for German documents 
including many English based acronyms. For better understanding, let's 
have a look at a simple example:

- Acronym: PSK
- English long: Phase Shift Keying
- German long: Phasenumtastung

Im most cases, there is not corresponding acronym in German, therefore 
I would like to use the English acronym in my document. Upon first 
use, the inserted text shall look like

*Phasenumtastung (PSK, Phase Shift Keying)*

Upon further use, only

*PSK*

shall be used.

Finally, in the list of acronyms, it shall look like:

*PSK - Phasenumtastung (Phase shift Keying)*

I tried to to setup something customized by renewing 
`\CustomAcronymFields`, `\SetCustomDisplayStyle` and `\glossaryentryfield` following the user documentation. I'm using the current version 3.01 of glossaries.

My approach is basically to put the string `", Phase Shift Keying"` into 
the description field while defining with `\newacronym` and then use it 
with customized `\defglsdisplayfirst` and `\glossaryentryfield`.

This is to demonstrate how it should look like:

```
% compile this with
%    pdflatex example.tex
%    makeindex  -s "example.ist" -t "example.alg" -o "example.acr" "example.acn"
%    pdflatex example.tex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain,sanitize={description=false,symbol=false}]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%% Desired style:
% first: "German long (acronym[, English long])"
% following: "acronym"
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
    name={\the\glsshorttok},%
    symbol={\the\glslongtok},%
    text={\the\glsshorttok},%
    plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}%
}

\renewcommand*{\SetCustomDisplayStyle}[1]{%
  % ##1 corresponds to the 'first' key
  % ##2 corresponds to the 'description' key
  % ##3 corresponds to the 'symbol' key
  % ##4 is the inserted text given by the final optional argument to
  % commands like \gls
  % The short form can be obtained via \glsentryshort{\glslabel}
  % The plural short form can be obtained via
  %\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}
  % The long form can be obtained via \glsentrylong{\glslabel}
  % The plural long form can be obtained via
  %\glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}
  \defglsdisplayfirst[#1]{##3 (##1##4##2##4)}%
  % ##1 corresponds to the 'text' key
  % the rest as above
  \defglsdisplay[#1]{##1##4}%
}
\SetCustomStyle

% start the glossary entries with capitals
\newglossarystyle{superuc}{%
  \glossarystyle{super}%
  \renewcommand*\glossaryentryfield[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{##2} & \makefirstuc{##4}##3\glspostdescription\space##5\\
  }
}



%% acronym definitions
% italic typeset foreign language terms
\newcommand{\foreignlang}[1]{\emph{#1}}
% define acronym with both German and English long
\newcommand{\newacropair}[4]{\newacronym[description={, \foreignlang{#4}}]{#1}{#2}{#3}}
% define acronym with only German long
\newcommand{\newacrogerman}[3]{\newacronym[description={}]{#1}{#2}{#3}}
% define acronym with only English long
\newcommand{\newacroenglish}[3]{\newacronym[description={}]{#1}{#2}{\foreignlang{#3}}}

% sample acronyms
% English acronym along with its common German counterpart
\newacropair{acr:adc}{ADC}{Analog-Digital-Umsetzer}{Analog to Digital Converter}
% English acronym without a common German counterpart
\newacroenglish{acr:dect}{DECT}{Digital Enhanced Cordless Telecommunications}
% German acronym
\newacrogerman{acr:din}{DIN}{Deutsches Institut fuer Normung}


% Alternative first - to be used if the first use is not nominative singular.
% Problem: I do not find a way to use glossaries' integrated 'first use' flag.
% This macro is my current dirty implementation. It always displays the full form
% and unsets the 'first use' flag afterwards. Bad things happen if at a later point
% it time, I decide to mention the same acronym earlier. I'll be using \glsalt again
% and end up in a double definition of the acronym, which I would like to avoid.
\newcommand{\glsalt}[2]{\glslink{#1}{#2 (\acrshort*{#1}\glsdesc*{#1})}\glsunset{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section{Problems}

% For the first mention, I'll be using \glsalt, since I need to display the 
% German text in genitive.
Die Aufloesung des \glsalt{acr:adc}{Analog-Digital-Umsetzers} beeinflusst\dots

% In the example below, I would need a plural form. That means an 's' would
% have to be attached to both the English acronym as well as the English long form.
% I have no clue how to implement that cleanly, due to my changes in
% \SetCustomDisplayStyle in the preamble.
Die Aufloesung der \glsalt{acr:adc}{Analog-Digital-Umsetzer} beeinflusst\dots


\section{Normal Cases}

\glsreset{acr:adc}

% These are only to show how it should look like for the 'normal' cases.
\gls{acr:adc} -- \gls{acr:adc}

\gls{acr:dect} -- \gls{acr:dect}

\gls{acr:din} -- \gls{acr:din}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=superuc,nonumberlist=false]

\end{document}
```

This works for me unless I don't have to use the plural form upon the 
first occurence. From then on, the concept behind glossaries, so far I 
can understand, does not really allow my tweak.

The main reason, to my understanding, is the fact that when defining a 
new acronym by `\newacronym`, besides the label, only one short form and 
one long form can be passed and accessed in `\CustomAcronymFields`. 
These two can be accessed by `\glsshorttok` and `\glslongtok` for storing 
them under the user-defined keys, such as `name`, `symbol`, `text`, 
etc. Especially the `description` key itself cannot be accessed at 
this stage.

From the conceptual point of view, it would be helpful if all three 
forms (short, English long, German long) could be passed to 
`\newacronym` separately and then concatenated in a customized fashion 
to be finally stored with their corresponding keys, including 
`firstplural` and `longplural`. Note that for my example, I would e.g. 
have to append an "s" for the plural forms of the short form as well 
as to the English long form and provide a used-defined plural form for 
the German long form in most cases.

For now, my only question is whether you think that my problem can 
still be solved with what glossaries offers so far. If not, would it 
make sense to try to redefine a couple of commands? I've had the 
impression that e.g. `\glsentryfull` has to be redefined. However, one 
major problem I fear is that most of these commands only take a subset 
of keys, such as only `short` and `long` (not `description`) in case 
of `\glsentryfull`.

Or is there even another package which would do my task without modifications?

Comment: Your question is lacking (like the orginal question on c.t.t) a complete minimal example that could be used for testing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. My question is more a conceptual one, therefore I did not create one yet. I will add one asap.

Comment: Well your example actually don't show your problem with the plural. Apart from this: You are writing a german text so I think you should try to translate also "Enhanced Data Rate". At second I think you are putting to much emphasis on the "foreign language" aspect. The main attribute of the text behind the acronym is not that it is in english but that it explains its origin. There could also stand a text like "first used in the novel ...". Also I doubt that you actually need language dependant \newacronym commands.

Comment: Well, this stuff is used in the context of communication technologies. 99% of the acronyms are English, and some of them do not have a _common_ German counterpart. So it is for EDR -- sure I could translate it to _erweiterte Datenrate_, however, in the context of the document, this is uncommon. Maybe EDR is not the best example, I will replace it by another one.

Comment: You should put @Ulrike in comments so that I get notified of your answers. I do understand your problem with the multitudity of english technical terms, nevertheless I do think you should make an effort to keep them at bay. But the main point of my comment was that imho you should change your point of view: don't divide your acronyms in "german" and "english" acronyms. Actually you seem to have currently at least 3 types: normal (DIN), commented (ADC), name with additional formating (EDR).

Comment: @Ulrike, I think I understand your doubts in my concept. Actually, I would be happy if I could use the native glossaries concept with _short_, _long_ and _description_. But I can't really see how that would fit in here (since it would require a more sophisticated way of generating the displayed test, which I am unable to implement right now). The additional formatting should not only be done for the third type you mention, but for any terms that are not German. That is, it is also used for `\newacropair`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) package. The translation is stored in the `user1` key. The `long-short-user` abbreviation style is designed to include additional information in the parenthetical material on first use. By default it picks up the information from the `user1` field.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,
            nomain,% don't create "main" glossary
            postdot% put a period after the description
           ]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

% \glscurrentfieldvalue only works with glossaries v4.23 (and above)
\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
 \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
 { (\glscurrentfieldvalue)}%
 {}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\newacronym[user1=Phase Shift Keying]{psk}{PSK}{Phasenumtastung}
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{Another Acronym}

\begin{document}    

First use: \gls{psk}. Subsequent use: \gls{psk}.

First use: \gls{aa}. Subsequent use: \gls{aa}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: First use: Phasenumtastung (PSK, Phase Shift Keying). Subsequent use: PSK. First use: Another Acronym (AA). Subsequent use: AA. Acronyms AA Another Acronym. 1 PSK Phasenumtastung (Phase Shift Keying). 1]

The post-description hook (`\glsxtrpostdesc`*category*) appends information after the description in the glossary. This is a convenient way of making a minor adjustment without having to define a new glossary style.

If you prefer to use `\newabbreviation` instead of `\newacronym`, you need to redefine `\glsxtrpostdescabbreviation` instead of `\glsxtrpostdescacronym` and use `\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-user}` instead of `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}`. (`\newacronym` implicitly sets `category=acronym` and `\newabbreviation` implicitly sets `category=abbreviation`.)

If you want to stick with just the base `glossaries` package, it's slightly more complicated. The translation is still provided in the `user1` field:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% define an acronym style for the acronyms with a translation:

\newacronymstyle{acronymslang}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{short-long}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
   (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}%
    \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}%
    {, \glsentryuseri{##1}}{})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
   (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}%
    \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}%
    {, \glsentryuseri{##1}}{})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
   (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}%
    \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}%
    {, \glsentryuseri{##1}}{})%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
   (\protect\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}%
    \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}%
    {, \glsentryuseri{##1}}{})%
  }%
}

\setacronymstyle{acronymslang}

\newacronym[user1=Phase Shift Keying]{psk}{PSK}{Phasenumtastung}
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{Another Acronym}

% glossary style for acronyms with a translation

\newglossarystyle{acronymslang}
{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription
    \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}{ (\glsentryuseri{##1})}{}%
    \space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\setglossarystyle{acronymslang}

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{psk}. Subsequent use: \gls{psk}.

First use: \gls{aa}. Subsequent use: \gls{aa}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

This doesn't have the benefit of the post-description hook so a custom glossary style is required. The difference between the two methods can be seen from the position of the period (full-stop) inserted after the description through the `postdot` or `postpunc=dot` (`glossaries-extra` only) or `nopostdot=false` package options. With the `glossaries-extra` post-description hook the terminating punctuation is placed after the hook.

My original answer used an old version of `glossaries` and had to use internal commands, which isn't desirable. It's better to update to a newer version and use one of the above methods instead. There's no custom glossary style as it uses a hack to append the `user1` contents to the `description` field.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoks\customtok

\renewcommand*{\newacronymhook}{%
 \edef\dosetkeys{\noexpand\setkeys{glossentry}{user1={},\the\glskeylisttok}}%
 \dosetkeys
 \ifcsempty{@glo@useri}%
 {%
   \expandafter\customtok\expandafter{\the\glsshorttok}%
 }%
 {%
   \edef\custom{\the\glsshorttok, \csexpandonce{@glo@useri}}%
   \expandafter\customtok\expandafter{\custom}%
 }%
}

\newcommand*{\custompostdesc}[1]{%
  \ifcsempty{glo@#1@useri}{}{ (\glsentryuseri{#1})}%
}

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  user1={},%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  description={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\custompostdesc{\the\glslabeltok}},%
  first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\customtok)},%
  firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix
    \space (\the\customtok)}%
  text={\the\glsshorttok},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1=Phase Shift Keying]{psk}{PSK}{Phasenumtastung}
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{Another Acronym}

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{psk}. Subsequent use: \gls{psk}.

First use: \gls{aa}. Subsequent use: \gls{aa}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Comment: @egreg could you please help me on modifying the code above so it is: OtherLanguage_long (PSK, EnglishLong). I want to store in user1 the OtherLanguage_long. And if possible to use user2 to set the plural for the OtherLanguage_long.

Comment: @jlanza I suggest you post a new question with a link back to this one.

Comment: I have posted the preliminary solution to my problem at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136634/glossaries-acronyms-two-languages  I used 2 custom tokens, on for singular and another for plural. I guess I can tune it a bit more automating the plural from the singular, but Spanish is quite strange on plurals ;)

Comment: Based on the solution I proposed or yours, do you know how to make the custompostdesc to be capitalized on the Glossaries list? I've tried plenty of things mainly from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103838/converting-text-to-title-case but I get errors :( Could you please help me on that?