# How to add translation to long form of acronym?

Tags: acronyms

I am currently using the `acronym` package to handle acronyms/abbreviations in my thesis.

I am writing in German, but I use a couple of English acronyms because either no German acronym exists or the English one simply more commonly used. So when introducing the acronym, I want/need to use the German word in text (as "long" form) but I want to include the English long form in parentheses alongside the (English) acronym. And of course, both German and English should show up in the list of acronyms.

- German Term: Steuergerät
- English Term: Electronic Control Unit
- Acronym: ECU

So in my text I'd like to have:

> .... Steuergerät( Electronic Control Unit, ECU) ....

and later simply have

> .... ECU ....

In the list of acronyms, it should show up as:

> ECU   Steuergerät (Electronic Control Unit)

or

> ECU Electronic Control Unit (Steuergerät)

Is there a way to include a translation in the long version of an acronym?

EDIT: As pointed out by @NicolaTalbot, the use case is the same than [Using the glossaries package for English acronyms in German documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/using-the-glossaries-package-for-english-acronyms-in-german-documents). Is there a way to achieve this with the `acronym` package as well or do I need to switch packages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Using the glossaries package for English acronyms in German documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/using-the-glossaries-package-for-english-acronyms-in-german-documents)?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes, that pretty much looks like what I am after...Is there a way to do this with the `acronym` package as well?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Yes, sorry, a messed up the example. I will modify/extend it.

Comment: @JohannesS.Sorry, I don't know how to do this with `acronym` as I've never used that package. If you do decide to switch, the `glossaries` package option `shortcuts` will enable commands like `\ac` and `\acs`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you, I will look into this.

Comment: Okay, I switched to the `glossaries` package. The code was less intimidating than expected...copy-pasting just worked fine.

Comment: For what it's worth: the [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package v1.3 provides the `foreign` key for this.

Comment: Funny how this covers exactly the same example as my question...

Comment: @JohannesS. you might have given me some inspiration... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I already said in the comments: [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) provides the `foreign` key for cases like this. Nonetheless: here is a way to achieve what you want with [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym). The usage is similar to `acronym`'s `\acroextra`. The code below defines a command `\acroforeign{<foreign long form>}` that is to be placed *inside the second mandatory argument* of `\acro`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

% provides \AtBeginEnvironment, \patchcmd and \csdef:
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acroforeign}[1]{}

% patch the environment to print the foreign definition:
\AtBeginEnvironment{acronym}{%
  \def\acroforeign#1{ (#1)}%
}

% patch the acronym definition to safe the foreign definition:
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix{}@acro\endcsname
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\def\acroforeign##1{\csdef{ac@#1@foreign}{##1, }}}
  {}
  {\fail}

% %   renew the first output to include the foreign definition if given:
\renewcommand*{\@acf}[2][\AC@linebreakpenalty]{%
  \ifAC@footnote
    \acsfont{\csname ac@#2@foreign\endcsname\AC@acs{#2}}%
    \footnote{\AC@placelabel{#2}\AC@acl{#2}{}}%
  \else
    \acffont{%
      \AC@placelabel{#2}\AC@acl{#2}%
      \nolinebreak[#1] %
      \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\csname ac@#2@foreign\endcsname\AC@acs{#2}})}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#2}\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

First: \ac{ECU}, \ac{BW}

Subsequent: \ac{ECU}, \ac{BW}

List:
\begin{acronym}[ECU]
  \acro{ECU}{Steuerger\"at\acroforeign{Electronic Control Unit}}
  \acro{BW}{Baden-W\"urttemberg}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The acro package is working great.

Comment: I am getting the error "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{acronym}" after copy and pasting cgnieders approach. Do you have any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @LN-12 my answer was outdated. I added an updated version.

Comment: If I copy your solution for the acronym package it doesnt compile. I get `undefined control sequence` at `\fail` and `\AC@prefix`. Why is that ? I want to use acronym because I wrote my whole thesis with it and I dont want to switch back to acro.