# Latex acronym package: english terms with german translation

Tags: acronyms

im writing an german text with latex where im using the acronym package where it looks like this:

> Situation Awareness (SA)

But when i have english terms i have to declare them with the german translation like this:

> Situationsbewusstsein (SA, engl. Situation Awareness)

Does somebody know if that is possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Have a look at [How to add translation to long form of acronym?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112222/how-to-add-translation-to-long-form-of-acronym)

Comment: Did my comment answer your question? If so I suggest we close this one as a duplicate