# How to add translation to form of some acronym?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, german

I am new to the LaTeX world,

I am currently using the acronym package to handle acronyms/abbreviations in my thesis. And I have to use this package.
At the moment I'm created a list of abbreviations, which has worked well so far. The list of abbreviations currently looks like this:

```
...
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
...
\begin{acronym}[PASCAL VOC]
    \acro{ann}[ANN]{Artificial Neural Networks}
    \acro{dl}[DL]{Deep Learning}
\end{acronym}
```

I can insert these in the text using `\ac{ann}`.

Now I would like to extend the abbreviations, so that I can use for example the following acronyms in my text:

Example:
Lorem ipsum **mittlerequadratische Abweichung (engl. Mean Squared Error, kurz: MSE)** eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna.

Likewise, in the further course of the text only **MSE** should appear in the abbreviation. So far I have not found a solution and have problems writing a function myself. Is it possible that someone will help me with this problem?

In fact I have already gone to the following thread ([How to add translation to long form of acronym?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112222/how-to-add-translation-to-long-form-of-acronym)). I only encountered an error while building (although I only copied the example).

In the following lines I get this one error message:

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix{}@acro\endcsname
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\def\acroforeign##1{\csdef{ac@#1@foreign}{##1, }}}
  {}
  {\fail}
```

=> Undefined control sequence. \expandafter\patchcmd\csname AC@\AC@prefix

=> Undefined control sequence.  \fail

```
Ridge: \ac{ECU}, \ac{BW}

Subsequent: \ac{ECU}, \ac{BW}
```

=> Acronym 'Ecu' is not defined and Acronym 'BW' is not defined.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112222/ ?

Comment: @cgnieder In fact I have already found this. I only found an error while building (although I only copied the example).

I get a message in line 16 that it is an Undefined control sequence and could not solve the error by myself. 

I would also be happy if this problem was solved

Comment: @cgnieder could you reproduce the error messages or is there a nother way I can solve these problems?

Comment: An alternative to package `acronym` are packages from `glossaries` line. They have also informatory documentation that directly shows examples with acronyms that have declared translation. Have a look at it. Also, as always, next time provide a minimal working example of what are you doing; that allows someone to help specifically for your use case.

Comment: @TomášKruliš I would do the same but I only have certain packages to use and unfortunately glossaries are not included but only acronym.

Comment: @john-mueller Where does the requirement to use `acronym` instead of `glossaries` come from? I agree that `glossaries` is able to achieve this and it has been selected as a tag for the question.

Comment: @TobiBS from the template that I should use and should not manipulate with other packages. These are conditions that I have received and unfortunately cannot change