# Glossaries acronyms two languages

Tags: glossaries, languages, acronyms

I'm using glossaries package to make my list of acronyms. I'm writing in Spanish but some of my acronyms are in English. I want them to be displayed like:
Spanish description - English long (Short) -

I was thinking on using the description label in glossaries to include the Spanish description. However I don't know how to modify the \acX macros in order to display the acronym correctly (first time all, next just the short, etc.)

Any help or hint is more than welcome.

CU

Edit: After having [Using the glossaries package for English acronyms in German documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/using-the-glossaries-package-for-english-acronyms-in-german-documents) I need it to be modified to a format like:

OtherLanguage_long (Short, Long)
   Long (Short)

ie. --> Calidad de Servicio (QoS, Quality of Service)
        Internet Protocol (IP)

**Edit 2:** Problem solved... At least I think so.
I've created to tokens, one for plural and another for singular.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym, toc, shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoks\customtoksingular
\newtoks\customtokplural

\renewcommand*{\newacronymhook}{%
 \edef\dosetkeys{\noexpand\setkeys{glossentry}{user1={},\the\glskeylisttok}}%
 \dosetkeys
 \ifcsempty{@glo@useri}%
 {%
   %\expandafter\customtoksingular\expandafter{\the\glsshorttok\space(\the\glslongtok)}%
   \expandafter\customtoksingular\expandafter{\noexpand\acrfullformat{\the\glslongtok}{\the\glsshorttok}}%
 }%
 {%
   \edef\custom{\csexpandonce{@glo@useri}\space(\the\glsshorttok, \the\glslongtok)}%
   \expandafter\customtoksingular\expandafter{\custom}%
 }%
 \ifcsempty{@glo@userii}%
 {%
   %\expandafter\customtoksingular\expandafter{\the\glsshorttok\space(\the\glslongtok)}%
   \expandafter\customtokplural\expandafter{\noexpand\acrfullformat
           {\noexpand\glsentrylongpl{\the\glslabeltok}}%
           {\noexpand\glsentryshortpl{\the\glslabeltok}}}
 }%
 {%
   \edef\custom{\csexpandonce{@glo@userii}\space(\the\glsshorttok, \the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix)}%
   \expandafter\customtokplural\expandafter{\custom}%
 }%
}

\newcommand*{\custompostdesc}[1]{%
  \ifcsempty{glo@#1@useri}{}{ (\glsentryuseri{#1})}%
}

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  user1={},%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},%
  description={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\custompostdesc{\the\glslabeltok}},%
  first={\the\customtoksingular},%
  firstplural={\the\customtokplural},%
  % first={\the\glslongtok\space(\the\customtoksingular)},%
  %firstplural={\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix\space (the\customtoksingular},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1=interfaz de programaci\'{o}n de la aplicaci\'{o}n, user2=interfaces de programaci\'{o}n de la aplicaci\'{o}n]{api}{API}{Application Programming Interface}
\newacronym{aa}{AA}{Another Acronym}

\begin{document}

First use: Las \acp{api} ....  Subsequent use: \acp{api}

\glsresetall{}

First use: Las \ac{api} ....  Subsequent use: \ac{api}

First use: \gls{aa}. Subsequent use: \gls{aa}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be able to adapt [Using bi-lingual entries with the glossaries package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128334/using-bi-lingual-entries-with-the-glossaries-package) or [Using the glossaries package for English acronyms in German documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/using-the-glossaries-package-for-english-acronyms-in-german-documents).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I will have a look to it and get back

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I had a look at the links and based on your suggestion I have edited my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you upgrade to the latest version of [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) (v4.01 at time of writing) as it's more flexible. Here's an example that uses v4.01:

```
\documentclass[spanish,english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% Add new key for long Spanish form:
\glsaddkey
{longsp}% key
{}% default value
{\glsentrylongsp}% new command analogous to \glsentrylong
{\Glsentrylongsp}% new command analogous to \Glsentrylong
{\acrlongsp}% new command analogous to \acrlong
{\Acrlongsp}% new command analogous to \Acrlong
{\ACRlongsp}% new command analogous to \ACRlong

% Add new key for plural long Spanish form:
\glsaddkey
{longplsp}% key
{}% default value
{\glsentrylongplsp}% new command analogous to \glsentrylongpl
{\Glsentrylongplsp}% new command analogous to \Glsentrylongpl
{\acrlongplsp}% new command analogous to \acrlongpl
{\Acrlongplsp}% new command analogous to \Acrlongpl
{\ACRlongplsp}% new command analogous to \ACRlongpl

% Provide conditional to test if longsp/longplsp has been set
\newcommand*{\glsifhaslongsp}[3]{%
  \ifcsempty{glo@#1@longsp}{#3}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\glsifhaslongplsp}[3]{%
  \ifcsempty{glo@#1@longplsp}{#3}{#2}%
}

% Set up custom acronym style:
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},
  description={\the\glslongtok},%
}

% Set the display style for acronyms (used by commands like \gls, \glspl, \ac, \acp or \glsdisp)
\renewcommand*\SetCustomDisplayStyle[1]{%
  \defglsentryfmt[#1]{%
    \ifdefempty\glscustomtext
    {% \glsdisp not used
      \ifglsused\glslabel
      {% subsequent use
         \glsifplural
         {% plural
           \glscapscase
           {% subsequent, plural, no case change
             \glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert%
           }%
           {% subsequent, plural, first letter upper case
             \Glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert%
           }%
           {% subsequent, plural, all caps
             \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
           }%
         }%
         {% singular
           \glscapscase
           {% subsequent, singular, no case change
             \glsentryshort{\glslabel}\glsinsert%
           }%
           {% subsequent, singular, first letter upper case
             \Glsentryshort{\glslabel}\glsinsert%
           }%
           {% subsequent, singular, all caps
             \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentryshort{\glslabel}\glsinsert}%
           }%
         }%
      }%
      {% first use
         \glsifplural
         {% plural
           \glsifhaslongplsp\glslabel
           {% first use, plural, has Spanish long form
             \glscapscase
             {% first use, plural, Spanish, no case change
               \glsentrylongplsp{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel},\space
                \glsentrylongpl{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, plural, Spanish, first letter upper case
               \Glsentrylongplsp{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel},\space
                \glsentrylongpl{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, plural, Spanish, all caps
               \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentrylongplsp{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel},\space
                \glsentrylongpl{\glslabel})}%
             }%
           }%
           {% first use, plural, doesn't have Spanish long form
             \glscapscase
             {% first use, plural, no Spanish, no case change
               \glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, plural, no Spanish, first letter upper case
               \Glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, plural, no Spanish, all caps
               \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel})}%
             }%
           }%
         }%
         {% singular
           \glsifhaslongsp\glslabel
           {% first use, singular, has Spanish long form
             \glscapscase
             {% first use, singular, Spanish, no case change
               \glsentrylongsp{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel},\space
                \glsentrylong{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, singular, Spanish, first letter upper case
               \Glsentrylongsp{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel},\space
                \glsentrylong{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, singular, Spanish, all caps
               \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentrylongsp{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel},\space
                \glsentrylong{\glslabel})}%
             }%
           }%
           {% first use, singular, doesn't have Spanish long form
             \glscapscase
             {% first use, singular, no Spanish, no case change
               \glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, singular, no Spanish, first letter upper case
               \Glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel})%
             }%
             {% first use, singular, no Spanish, all caps
               \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel})}%
             }%
           }%
         }%
      }%
    }%
    {% \glsdisp used
      \glscustomtext
    }%
  }%
}

\SetCustomStyle

% Define a new glossary style that checks for the existence of
% the longsp field.
\newglossarystyle{listsp}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}% base style on the list style
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
  \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
    \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    \glsifhaslongsp{##1}{\space(\glsentrylongsp{##1})}{}%
    \glspostdescription\space ##2}%
}

\newacronym
 [longsp=interfaz de programaci\'{o}n de la aplicaci\'{o}n,
  longplsp=interfaces de programaci\'{o}n de la aplicaci\'{o}n
 ]{api}{API}{Application Programming Interface}

\newacronym{aa}{AA}{Another Acronym}

\begin{document}

First use: Las \acp{api} ....  Subsequent use: \acp{api}

\glsresetall

First use: Las \ac{api} ....  Subsequent use: \ac{api}

First use: \gls{aa}. Subsequent use: \gls{aa}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=listsp]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Edit:**

If you upgrade to the latest version (v4.02, 2013/12/05) it's easier to define a new acronym style and have `\acf` match the style. (Although it's also possible to define acronym styles where they don't match, as is the case with the predefined `footnote` style where `\acr` doesn't use a footnote.) Here's the above example rewritten using v4.02 code:

```
\documentclass[spanish,english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% Add new key for long Spanish form:
\glsaddkey
{longsp}% key
{}% default value
{\glsentrylongsp}% new command analogous to \glsentrylong
{\Glsentrylongsp}% new command analogous to \Glsentrylong
{\acrlongsp}% new command analogous to \acrlong
{\Acrlongsp}% new command analogous to \Acrlong
{\ACRlongsp}% new command analogous to \ACRlong

% Add new key for plural long Spanish form:
\glsaddkey
{longplsp}% key
{}% default value
{\glsentrylongplsp}% new command analogous to \glsentrylongpl
{\Glsentrylongplsp}% new command analogous to \Glsentrylongpl
{\acrlongplsp}% new command analogous to \acrlongpl
{\Acrlongplsp}% new command analogous to \Acrlongpl
{\ACRlongplsp}% new command analogous to \ACRlongpl

% Provide conditional to test if longsp/longplsp has been set
\newcommand*{\glsifhaslongsp}[3]{%
  \ifcsempty{glo@#1@longsp}{#3}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\glsifhaslongplsp}[3]{%
  \ifcsempty{glo@#1@longplsp}{#3}{#2}%
}

% Define new acronym style:

\newacronymstyle{spanish}
{% base the display style on 'long-short'
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}%
{% base the definitions on 'long-short'
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%  
% Make some custom modifications for the first use display.
% Singular, no case change:
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsifhaslongsp{##1}%
   {% has Spanish version:
      \glsentrylongsp{##1}##2\space
      (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}, \glsentrylong{##1})%
   }%
   {%
     \glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
     (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
   }%
  }%
% Singular, first letter upper case:
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsifhaslongsp{##1}%
   {% has Spanish version:
      \Glsentrylongsp{##1}##2\space
      (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}}, \glsentrylong{##1})%
   }%
   {%
     \Glsentrylong{##1}##2\space
     (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{##1}})%
   }%
  }%
% Plural, no case change:
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsifhaslongplsp{##1}%
   {% has Spanish version:
      \glsentrylongplsp{##1}##2\space
      (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}, \glsentrylongpl{##1})%
   }%
   {%
     \glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
     (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
   }%
  }%
% Plural, first letter upper case:
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
    \glsifhaslongplsp{##1}%
    {% has Spanish version:
      \Glsentrylongplsp{##1}##2\space
      (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}}, \glsentrylongpl{##1})%
    }%
    {%
      \Glsentrylongpl{##1}##2\space
      (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{##1}})%
    }%
  }%
}

% switch to the new style:
\setacronymstyle{spanish}

% Define a new glossary style that checks for the existence of
% the longsp field.
\newglossarystyle{listsp}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}% base style on the list style
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
  \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
    \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    \glsifhaslongsp{##1}{\space(\glsentrylongsp{##1})}{}%
    \glspostdescription\space ##2}%
}

\newacronym
 [longsp=interfaz de programaci\'{o}n de la aplicaci\'{o}n,
  longplsp=interfaces de programaci\'{o}n de la aplicaci\'{o}n
 ]{api}{API}{Application Programming Interface}

\newacronym{aa}{AA}{Another Acronym}

\begin{document}

First use: Las \acp{api} ....  Subsequent use: \acp{api}

\glsresetall

First use: Las \ac{api} ....  Subsequent use: \ac{api}

First use: \gls{aa}. Subsequent use: \gls{aa}.

Full form: \acf{api}, \acf{aa}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=listsp]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Edit 2:**

In answer to @cacamailg's comment regarding only using the non-English version, the simplest method is just to define a set of commands that check the first use flag like this:

```
\newcommand*{\acfor}[2][]{%
 \ifglsused{#2}%
 {\acrshort[#1]{#2}}%
 {\acrlongsp[#1]{#2} (\acrshort[#1]{#2})\glsunset{#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\Acfor}[2][]{%
 \ifglsused{#2}%
 {\Acrshort[#1]{#2}}%
 {\Acrlongsp[#1]{#2} (\acrshort[#1]{#2})\glsunset{#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\acplfor}[2][]{%
 \ifglsused{#2}%
 {\acrplshort[#1]{#2}}%
 {\acrlongplsp[#1]{#2} (\acrshortpl[#1]{#2})\glsunset{#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\Acplfor}[2][]{%
 \ifglsused{#2}%
 {\Acrshortpl[#1]{#2}}%
 {\Acrlongplsp[#1]{#2} (\acrshortpl[#1]{#2})\glsunset{#2}}%
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
\acfor{api}. Next use: \acfor{api}.
```

This has some limitations, for example, you can't use the final insert optional argument used by commands like `\gls`.

Comment: Still have not being mirrored to MikTex. Hope in a few days it will. Besides, is there any way to make the sp version to be the first letter in first word in capitals? Is it using Gls version? And for all the words in the acronym? I will try to check when possible to update.

Comment: @jlanza The `\glscapscase` part is the bit of code that checks whether `\gls`/`\glspl`, `\Gls`/`\Glspl` or `\GLS`/`\GLSpl` is being used. (`\glsifplural` is used to determine whether the singular or plural form is used.) So, when `\Gls` is used (and `longsp` has been set), the code branch with `\Glsentrylongsp` is used, which makes the first letter of the sp version uppercase.

Comment: Hope it's the last question. Is there any way to use the \acf but including the Spanish version? Right now it only displays the eng and shorteng.

Comment: @jlanza The easiest way to do that is to upgrade to v4.02. I've updated my answer to show how.

Comment: I've found a problem with the code provided. It is the recursivity. Let's say I have an acronym that includes another acronym, ie API (application... ) and HLAPI(High level API). If you define the second including the first the acronym is not well extended (\newacronym{HLAPI}{HLAPI}{High Level \ac{API}} it extends to High Level API (API) instead of (HLAPI)

Comment: @jlanza It's not a good idea to nest entries like that. Aside from the code not being intuitive enough to know what you want, you'll end up with nested hyperlinks if you're using `hyperref`. I recommend you just do `\newacronym{HLAPI}{HLAPI}{High Level Application Programming Interface}` or `\newacronym[see=API]{HLAPI}{HLAPI}{High Level Application Programming Interface}`

Comment: Again another request. Could you help me on adapting the glossaries to set \emph for acronyms in another language. I have acronyms both in eng and esp. The one only in eng have to be emph but the ones in esp not. Is there any way of including a flag or similar in the macros.

Comment: @jlanza It may be better to post it as a new question with a link back to this one.

Comment: Is it possible to define a key, lets say `\acfor{}` and frieds that prints the foreigner version. For example, suppose that the foreigner language is Portuguese. If I type `\ac{TV}` it would give me `Television (TV)`. however, if I type `\acfor{TV}` it would give me `Televisão (TV)`. The problem arises because my main document is written in English, but it has one page that is written in Portuguese and has the same acronyms used in the English version.

Comment: @cacamailg I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot after my comment I defined an `\acfor{}` similar to yours but I may define while typing the long version of the acronym. See below.

Answer (score 2):

A new version for `\acfor{}`. In text you may use `\acfor[Televisão]{TV}` to achieve the result `Televisão (TV)` in the first run and `TV` in the others. This generates the link to `Television` entry as defined below:

```
\newacronym{TV}{TV}{Television}
```

If the first argument is not provided, `\acfor{TV}` gives *Television* (TV) in the first run and `TV` in the others.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

% A version of '\ac{}' to be used in foreign texts
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\acfor}{ o m }{%
    \ifglsused{#2}{% verifies if entry has been marked as used
        \glslink{#2}{\glsentryshort{#2}}% if yes, use short version 
    }{% else
        \IfValueTF{#1}{% verifies if there is a label
            \glslink{#2}{#1\space(\glsentryshort{#2})}% if yes, use and link it
            \glsunset{#2}% mark as used
        }{% else
            \glslink{#2}{\emph{\glsentrylong{#2}}\space(\glsentryshort{#2})}% emphasize the foreign text  
            \glsunset{#2}% mark as used
        }%
    }%
}
```