# Change order of acronyms text in two languages acronyms with glossaries-extra

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I'm using glossaries-extra for spanish and english acronims, and works well for my. I followed this posts:

[Using the glossaries package for English acronyms in German documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/using-the-glossaries-package-for-english-acronyms-in-german-documents)

But I want to change the order in that the acronyms is showed in the list in the case that user1 is defined.

Im using this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         

\usepackage[acronym, nomain, nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\renewcommand{\glsxtrpostdescacronym}{%
 \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}%
 { (\textit{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
 {}%
}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1=Signal to Noise Ratio]{snr}{SNR}{relación señal a ruido}
\newacronym{utn}{UTN}{Universidad Tecnológica Nacional}

\begin{document}    

Primer uso de \gls{snr}. Segundo uso de \gls{snr}.

Primer uso de \gls{utn}. Segundo uso de \gls{utn}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

and I get:

[image]

But I want:

[image]

In summary I want to show

**short *user1* (long)**

if user1 is defined, else I want to show only

**short long**

Can somebody help me?

Best Regards,

Matias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches that I can think of. The first is to define a custom style that's modified to check for the `user1` field. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         

\usepackage[acronym, nomain, nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1=Signal to Noise Ratio]{snr}{SNR}{relación señal a ruido}
\newacronym{utn}{UTN}{Universidad Tecnológica Nacional}

\newglossarystyle{bilinguallist}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}% base it on the list style
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
          \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
      \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{##1}%
      {\textit{\glscurrentfieldvalue} (\glossentrydesc{##1})}%
      {\glossentrydesc{##1}}%
      \glspostdescription\space ##2}%
}
\setglossarystyle{bilinguallist}% set this new style

\begin{document}

Primer uso de \gls{snr}. Segundo uso de \gls{snr}.

Primer uso de \gls{utn}. Segundo uso de \gls{utn}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

The second method modifies `\glossentrydesc` which is used in all the predefined glossary styles when displaying the description.

With the base `glossaries` package, this command just checks if the entry has been defined and displays the description. The `glossaries-extra` package redefines this command to set the current abbreviation style and check for the attributes `glossdescfont` and `glossdesc` before displaying the description.

If you're not interested in using the `glossdescfont` and `glossdesc` attributes, you could just redefine `\glossentrydesc` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         

\usepackage[acronym, nomain, nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1=Signal to Noise Ratio]{snr}{SNR}{relación señal a ruido}
\newacronym{utn}{UTN}{Universidad Tecnológica Nacional}

\renewcommand{\glossentrydesc}[1]{%
 \glsdoifexistsorwarn{#1}%
 {%
   \glssetabbrvfmt{\glscategory{#1}}%
   \ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{#1}%
   {\textit{\glscurrentfieldvalue} (\glsentrydesc{#1})}%
   {\glsentrydesc{#1}}%
 }%
}

\begin{document}

Primer uso de \gls{snr}. Segundo uso de \gls{snr}.

Primer uso de \gls{utn}. Segundo uso de \gls{utn}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: Hello Nicola, both solutions works well. I took the second one because in the real document i'm using `\setglossarystyle{long}`. Thank you.