# Multilingual abbreviations

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, translate

So, I know there is "glossaries" package which I can use to create abbreviations table.

But, since I'm writing my paper in Croatian I should also have a translation for that abbreviation description.

Something like this:

```
HTML    Hyper Text Markup Language        Croatian translation of HTML
PHP     PHP Hyper Text Processor          Croatian translation of PHP
...
```

Is there a way to do something like this in automated/semantic manner?

I'd like to define my abbreviations in the following way if possible:

```
\newacronym{html}{HTML}{Hyper Text Markup Language}{Croatian translation of HTML}
```

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31300/

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, croatian, russian]{babel}

\newcommand{\langdepmacro}[4]{%
    \newcommand{#1}{%
        \iflanguage{croatian}{#2}{%
        \iflanguage{russian}{#3}{%
        \iflanguage{english}{#4}{}%
        }}%
    }%
}

\langdepmacro{\newacronym}{HTML1}{HTML2}{HTML3}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\newacronym

\selectlanguage{russian}
\newacronym

\selectlanguage{croatian}
\newacronym
\end{document}
```

[image]