# How to put translations in parentheses on first use with glossaries-extra?

Tags: glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I am currently writing a thesis in Swedish and have chosen to use Swedish translations for certain terms. Since they are not well known in Swedish, I would like to present the English term in parentheses on first use:

> ... kontinuerlig integration (eng. *continuous integration*) ...

Subsequent use:

> ... kontinuerlig integration ...

This is different from the style in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77561/183394) that uses `glossaries-extra` with the `long-short-user` style because I want no `short` (acronym) and I want the `long` (Swedish term) to be output in subsequent usages. A style like `user-long`, if that existed.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution, a workaround of sorts, is formatting entries like this (with `bib2gls`):

```
@entry{kontinuerlig-integration,
    name = {kontinuerlig integration},
    description = {Eng. \emph{continuous integration}, ...},
    long = {continuous integration},
    category = {translation}
}
```

With style:

```
\setabbreviationstyle[translation]{short-long}
\renewcommand*{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{eng. \emph{#1}}
```

This results in the desired formatting, but seems wrong. According to section 3.4.2 of [the manual](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.pdf) the style doesn't set the `regular` attribute which, according to chapter 5, indicates that it is an abbreviation. I wouldn't say that it is.

Also, this requires setting the translation as `long`. I would say that the English term is something else, maybe `user`.

So this solution seems wrong. I would appreciate any less hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to glossaries/glossaries-extra, try the code below. I recommend an extra glossary (here defined as 'trans') so its entries will only show up where you use \printglossary[type=trans].

**Update #1:** i overlooked the 'only on first use' demand

**Update #2:** *sigh* ... i missed the replacement of the sample text & figure

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newcommand{\glsEngInSwedish}[1]{%
    \ifglsused{#1}%
    {\gls{#1}}
    {\gls{#1} (engl. \glsentryEnglish{#1})}%
    \glsunset{#1}% ensure flag for use
}

\glsaddkey
{english}           % key
{\glsentrytext{todo}}   % default value
{\glsentryEnglish}  % command analogous to \glsentrytext
{\GlsentryEnglish}  % command analogous to \Glsentrytext
{\glsEnglish}       % command analogous to \glstext
{\GlsEnglish}       % command analogous to \Glstext
{\GLSEnglish}       % command analogous to \GLStext
\glssetnoexpandfield{english}

\newglossary*{trans}{Translations}
\newglossaryentry{test}
{
    type=trans,
    name={swedish word},
    english={english translation},
    description={testDesc},
}

\begin{document}
    First use of \glsEngInSwedish{test} as well as second use of \glsEngInSwedish{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]