# How to print glossary math symbol in bold?

Tags: glossaries, bm

I would like to print the first usage of a math symbol defined in my glossary in **bold** without defining a new glossary entry.

Using the text environment `\textbf{\glssymbol{T1}}` has no effect, because the symbol is in math mode.

Using the symbol in math mode does not work either: `$\glssymbol{T1}$`.

How do I print the math symbol in bold?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{bm}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{T1}{name={T1}, symbol={\ensuremath{T_1}}, description={longitudinal relaxation time}}
\newglossaryentry{T1bold}{name={T1}, symbol={\ensuremath{\bm{T_1}}}, description={longitudinal relaxation time (bold entry)}}

\begin{document}
This is the first time I use \textbf{\glssymbol{T1}} (should be \textbf{bold} like \glssymbol{T1bold}) and this the second time: \glssymbol{T1} (not bold).

Defining another symbol in the glossary leads to a second entry:
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{T_1}}` or `\boldmath\ensuremath{T_1}`?

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote above, this would apply to every single usage of that symbol, not only a single one.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the bold usage is the first in the main text, as opposed to in the glossary?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the optional user fields to declare your bold variable. Its much easier to handle than to define a new command. Tip: you could also define a new gls field (say 'glsBoldVar', compare your problem to my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488400/how-to-put-translations-in-parentheses-on-first-use-with-glossaries-extra/525630#525630))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{bm}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{T1}{name={T1}, 
    symbol={\ensuremath{T_1}},
    user1={\ensuremath{\bm{T_1}}},
    description={longitudinal relaxation time}
}
 description={longitudinal relaxation time (bold entry)}}

\begin{document}
    This is the first time I use \textbf{\glssymbol{T1}} (should be \textbf{bold} like \glsuseri{T1}) and this the second time: \glssymbol{T1} (not bold).

    Defining another symbol in the glossary leads to a second entry:
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath` is a more standard command than `\bm`. It will work even when you load `bm`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the `\text` environment in a bold math (`bm`) mode.

As a new command, this looks like:

```latex
\newcommand{\glssymbold}[1]{\ensuremath{\bm{\text{\glssymbol{#1}}}}}
```

that can be used like this:

```latex
\glssymbold{T1}
```

Comment: Note that `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath` is a more standard command than `\bm`. It will work even when you load `bm`.